How can I convert a nested image array in Pandas to PySpark?
I'm unsure how to handle some errors that I'm getting when converting a pandas dataframe into a PySpark dataframe. My Pandas dataframe has a column "array_output", which is an array created from an image using OpenCV. It looks something like this:
array([[[255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        ...,
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       [[255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        ...,
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]],
...

Converting the dataframe to PySpark gives me the following error:
UserWarning: createDataFrame attempted Arrow optimization because 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled' is set to true; however, failed by the reason below:
  Can only convert 1-dimensional array values

I've tried flattening the array with this:
.apply(lambda x: [item for sublist in x for item in sublist])

But that doesn't seem to work either, as I get the same error.
Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

There is no need for flattening. Just define the correct schema and convert it directly as follows:
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.types as T
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

data = {
    'array_output': [
        [[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255]],
        [[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255]],
        [[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255]]
    ]
}
pdf = pd.DataFrame(data)

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

array_schema = T.StructType([
    T.StructField("array_output", T.ArrayType(T.ArrayType(T.IntegerType())), True)
])

spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf, schema=array_schema)

spark_df.printSchema()

spark_df.show(truncate=False)

Output:
root
 |-- array_output: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)

+---------------------------------------------------+
|array_output                                       |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|[[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255]]|
|[[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255]]|
|[[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255]]|
+---------------------------------------------------+

